# Android: combine Social Login and basic authentication

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, google-plus

I was asking myself how developers combine basic authentication (like username & password) with social logins like facebook & G+. So how do I integrate users that use social logins with those who sign up using username and password? Do the Social APIs give me some kind of token which I can save in my database to check whether the user is logged in / registered or not?

UPDATE:

I think I have to describe my problem more precisely. My App is communicating with a backend service (simple REST API). For that backend calls I have to make sure the user is registered & logged in. All the samples I have seen for now are just like login and then see client side information, but never communication with a secured backend system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out how to deal with it.

e.g. Facebook:
 1. Client requests token from facebook
 2. Client sents token to my server
 3. my server makes a request to facebook with the token to check that the fb-user exists
 4. my server creates my app specific user in my database (e.g. username: ..., usertype: facebook !!)
 5. the next time a user makes an API call, my server will check the token again by requesting facebook

Answer (score 0):

You can get Facebook SDK(API) For Android [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)

You can fins some good Examples which are there on developers site of Facebook. They Have Explained How we can check if user is logged in or not .

Also there is Another Library which Have made Facebook Login and Other Features simple which is [Simple Facebook](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook) . If you are just Beginning Android Programming then this will be easy.

And For Google+ also they have API. which you can Find [HERE](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in)

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. I think I have to describe my problem more precisely. My App is communicating with a backend service (simple REST API). For that backend calls I have to make sure the user is registered & logged in. All the samples I have seen for now are just like login and then see client side information, but never communication with a secured backend system.